# How can I make a WireBox injected dependency available to a constructor method?

Tags: dependency-injection, coldfusion, cfml, coldbox, wirebox

In this example, I have a model object called `test.cfc` which has a dependency `testService.cfc`.

`test` has WireBox inject `testService` through a property declaration.  The object looks like this:

```
component {

     property name="testService" inject="testService";

     /**
     *  Constructor
     */
     function init() {

         // do something in the test service
         testService.doSomething();

         return this;

     }

 }
```

For reference, `testService` has a single method called `doSomething()` which dumps out some text:

```
component
     singleton
{

     /**
     *  Constructor
     */
     function init() {

         return this;

     }


     /**
     *  Do Something
     */
     function doSomething() {

         writeDump( "something" );

     }

 }
```

The problem is, WireBox doesn't seem to inject `testService` until after the constructor `init()` method fires.  So, if I run this in my handler:

```
prc.test = wirebox.getInstance(
     name = "test"
);
```

I get the following error message: `Error building: test -> Variable TESTSERVICE is undefined.. DSL: , Path: models.test`

Just for sanity sake, if I modify `test` so that `testService` gets referenced after the object is constructed, everything works fine.  The problem seems to be isolated to constructor methods.

How can I make sure my dependencies can be referenced in my object constructor methods?  Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the order of construction, you can't use property or setter injections in the `init()` method.  Instead, you can access them in the `onDIComplete()` method.  I realized the WireBox docs only had a passing reference to this, so I have added this excerpt:

https://wirebox.ortusbooks.com/usage/injection-dsl/id-model-empty-namespace#cfc-instantiation-order

CFC Building happens in this order.

1. Component is instantiated with `createObject()`
2. CF automatically runs the pseudo constructor (any code outside the a method declaration)
3. The `init()` method is called (if it exists), passing any constructor args
4. Property (mixin) and setting injection happens
5. The `onDIComplete()` method is called (if it exists)

So the proper version of your CFC would be as follows:

```
component {

     property name="testService" inject="testService";

     /**
     *  Constructor
     */
     function init() {
         return this;
     }

     /**
     *  Called after property and setter injections are processed
     */
     function onDIComplete() {
         // do something in the test service
         testService.doSomething();
     }

 }
```

Note, it would also be acceptable to switch to constructor injection, but my personal preference is property injection due to the reduced boilerplate of needing to receive the argument and persist it locally.

https://wirebox.ortusbooks.com/usage/wirebox-injector/injection-idioms